# Remove redundant markers and circles from google_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I'm using google_maps_flutter to display only specific markers on the map. Unfortunately, there are tons of other markers and circles on the map that interrupt the experience (Restaurants, Stores and so on). How can I disable or remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it can be made by styling the map and removing unwanted parts away. You can also make some sick looking design too. Very useful.

Link:

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com